# bitmap.save changes its pixelFormat to 32-bit depth

Tags: c#, bitmap, save

I'm facing an issue which I can't resolve somehow, so I decided to ask you guys.

I have really simple code:

```
public void OpenSaveImageDialog(Bitmap bitmapImage)
    {
        var dlg = new SaveFileDialog
        {
            DefaultExt = DialogType.Image.defaultExt,
            Filter = DialogType.Image.filter
        };

        dlg.ShowDialog();

        bitmapImage.Save(dlg.FileName);
    }
```

Funcion parameters is a Bitmap with pixelFormat equal to 24bppRgb. It is really essential for me to preseve pixelFormat and bit depth during the save operation. But after I save the file and check its properties it's saved as 32 bit depth image. Why is that? How to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Set the ImageFormat to select between format with 24bit or 32bit : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You are saving the image in the PNG file format.  Yes, the PNG codec always uses 32bpp.  Use the Save() method overload that lets you specify the ImageFormat, you probably favor Bmp.  Make sure the filename extension matches, crystal ball says that it doesn't right now.

Comment: Thanks, but It doesn't work.

I've tried earlier to replace saving with:

bitmapImage.Save(dlg.FileName, ImageFormat.Bmp);

But it doesn't work. It saves as bmp as well and doesn't keep pixel format.

Comment: Then you created your Bitmap object wrong and your assumption that it is 24bpp is not correct.  The default you get when you don't use the Bitmap constructor overload that specifies the PixelFormat is one that matches your video adapter.  Always 32bpp on any modern machine.

Comment: O well I really think my assumption is right. Let me put it this way:

https://i.imgur.com/GGVrDNN.png

As you can see. I am openning my save dialog with bitmap that is 24bpp, saving it with the save method (adding ImageFormat.Bmp makes no difference), and then I open it with my code and PixelFormat has changed. Also checked it in windows explorer.

Comment: The screenshot partially shows the code that loaded the bitmap.  Unfortunately the critical part is covered up with debugger windows.  The new statement at the end of the method is very fishy.  If it is `new Bitmap(bitmap)` then you get a 32bpp image.

Comment: It is just my wrapper class that saves bytes and bmp both in one object. You can see the return type of the function is ImageFile which I've created for myself. I really checked if I am opening bitmap with a correct format like ten times, stop worrying about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following extension method to save as Format24bppRgb

```
public static class ImageExtensions
{
    public static Bitmap ImageTo24bpp(this Image img)
    {
        var bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            gr.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height));
        return bmp;
    }
}
```

how to use and save to file named fname:

```
        var image = bitmapImage.ImageTo24bpp();
        //convert image to bytes[]
        ImageConverter imgCon = new ImageConverter();
        var bytes=  (byte[])imgCon.ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));
        //save to filename
        File.WriteAllBytes(fname,bytes);
```

**Edit2:**

You can use the following method to save the image as ImageTo24bpp

```
public void    SaveAsImageTo24bpp( Image img,string fname)
    {
        var bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            gr.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height));         

        ImageConverter imgCon = new ImageConverter();
        var bytes = (byte[])imgCon.ConvertTo(bmp, typeof(byte[]));
         File.WriteAllBytes(fname,bytes);
    }
```

Comment: Your sollution actually works. It's strange that I have to convert like this. I am putting Bitmap with the same pixel format as a parameter and can save it with preserving this info. This is strange...I wonder tho, why does image size change? After I save image with 3x3 px that was previously 90 bytes with your method, the new Image size is 137 bytes. Where does this change come from? I know this may be stupid but it's essential for my work to know such things, meh.

Comment: what the extension you save image before/after conversion

Comment: For 24 bit images (24bppRgb), I open one with is 32x27px and 2,58kb, then after saving it with this method it is 231B o.0.

Comment: I've tested it further and ~800x600 24bpp bitmap that has a lot of the same color (just painted squares in ms paint) after saving is compressed to 5,37kb having the same resolution. It doesn't seem like a bmp image to me o.o

Comment: I modified the code, try it. Dump the result of the old and new file , and review both in painter.

Comment: I've tested, unfortunately nothing changed....

Old method:
24bpp image (800x600) Before/After saving = 1,37MB / 8,00kb
New method:
24bpp image (800x600) Before/After saving = 1,37MB / 8,00kb

There is some kind of compression is going on if the bmp image with such resollution has only 8kb...

Comment: Ive tested it also on more real images where is a lot of pixel differences and image weight has been reduced from 1,4MB to 900KB.

Comment: I've found that it's compression matches png format. Even tho file is saved as bmp, if I open it with Paint and try to save it as~ the format that is used is PNG by default.

Comment: yes,PNG format (vector format), BMP is (pixel format), so png has less size with same quality as original.

Comment: so, you want BMP file with Format24bppRgb

Comment: Yes, but saving it (for ex the way you proposed) changes its format and I cant retrieve Format24bppRgb  image without silly png compression.

Comment: Is there any image processing on these image?. Why BMP? .

Comment: Oh well let's say it the other way.

Is there any working code with will do simple following thing:
read 24bpp from desktop, save it as another 24bpp with the exact same size as original and name with copy at the end? Cuz this simple task seems to be impossible to do with c# as im trying it for few hours now.

Comment: If you have bmp file 24bit , save it as byte[] to a file , no more processing is needed.

Comment: Oh the thing is that basic funcionality is ok. The problem with writting bytes is that after I read them to Bitmap the bytes aren't the same. To be more precise, I am working with steganography (changing LSB's of pixels). This is why it is so important to me to write 24bpp and read 24bpp as the same exact object. default bitmap.save method compress it, bitmap.save with ImageFormat.bmp changes bits so they are not the same after I read object, the same is for just dumping bytes to file. I guess my problem is more complicated than I thought.